# Tomcat 7.0.x Manager login problem

Tags: authentication, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm trying to access the manager app, but I can't login. I get the logon screen, but when I enter the username and password, the login screen keeps coming back. Any suggestions?

This is what I've done:
The manager app is deployed  in $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/manager

Part of the **server.xml** file:

```
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
  type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
  description="User database that can be updated and saved"
  factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
  pathname="$CATALINA_BASE/conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
...
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
    resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
</Realm>
```

**tomcat-users.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat-user" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
  <user username="tocmat2" password="tomcat" roles="manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

In $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/**manager.xml**:

```
<Context privileged="true"
     docBase="path/to/webapps/manager">
</Context>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
pathname="$CATALINA_BASE/conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

to

```
pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

Comment: Hi, in my case, still not working.

<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui,manager-script"/>

pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml"